# Cannot open Desktop Settings and Energy Saver settings

Tags: macos, settings

i don't kwow why, but i can't able to open Preferences settings options like Desktop and Energy.

It show me this error:

[image]

> **TRANSLATION:**
>   **error in preferences**
>   Cannot load the Desktop & Screensaver preference pane

What's the problem?
How can i solve this issue?

any idea?

Using OSX 10.7.3 with last updates.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a corrupted System Preferences .plist file

You can remove the current .plist file in *~/library/preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist* drag that .plist to the desktop (as a backup) and try System Preferences again. It will automatically create a new, working .plist file.

Comment: uhm.... and if i don't have this file?? I searched entire disk, but nothing.

Comment: Try it in here ~/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

Comment: Nothing appened. Also restarted system.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from [here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/tg.online/osx/sysprefs/#103). Or you can use Michiel's. They are similar,except that the method below doesn't back up your plist.

1. Quit the System Preferences application, if it is running.
2. Launch the Terminal application (found in /Applications/Utilities/).
3. Type sudo -s and press Return
4. Enter the password for the current user profile (NOT the root password).
5. Type cd /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration and press Return (note case sensitivity).
6. Type mv preferences.plist preferences.plist.old and press Return.

Comment: Nothing appened. Also restarted system.

Comment: Try the method outlined here https://discussions.apple.com/message/17741838#17741838